# Direction of electron in car circuit

Tags: electrical, battery

I read this somewhere. "*Electrons flow from Negative to Positive. This is called Electron flow. Originally it was believed they flowed from Positive to Negative. This was later found to be incorrect and we call this Conventional Current*."

Why is negative terminal of battery is connected to chassis/car body? Can someone explain how current flows from car battery to e.g car radio (and other things) and return back to battery ? Why it is advised to always remove negative terminal first when removing battery ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more appropriate for https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't have enough rep to vote, but I think it'd go better on [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Agreed, electrical engineering or a physics forum would be more apropos.  BTW:  Electrons don't 'flow'...their kinetic energy does!

Answer (score 1):

Conventional Current assumes that current flows out of the positive terminal, through the circuit and into the negative terminal of the source. ... Electron Flow is what actually happens and electrons flow out of the negative terminal, through the circuit and into the positive terminal of the source.

This is not always true, years ago there were both positive and negative grounded systems in cars. It is done basically to save costs of expensive cabling. By connected one side (-) of the battery to the metal chassis, engine, it allows all items requiring power to only have to have the positive connection made and connect the negative feed directly to any part of the metal chassis.

There are a lot of answers but this is my favorite "Do not disconnect the positive (+) battery cable first! A slip of the wrench here creates a direct short to ground. Think instantaneous arc welder and possibility of igniting hydrogen that is given off by the battery during charging.

Comment: A big spark. I watched an impatient customer wirebrush a positive terminal, and the spark ignites the hydrogen gas and blew out the side of the battery. Acid and mess everywhere. I was a bystander, the working mechanic nearby did the cleanup, except for the suit the customer was wearing.